# From Mac & Ubuntu how to connect windows share path from python and list files and copy

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, smb

I want to connect to a windows share path through Python code in Mac(Dev) and Ubuntu(prod) and list the directories and traverse all directories in the path and search for files ending with *abc.html and retrieve those files alone.
 os.listdir isn't working.

From Finder in Mac I could connect to the the windows shared path with link like (smb:// ...).

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have a look at the [`pysmb`](https://pypi.org/project/pysmb/) module.

Comment: You'll need to mount the file share on the Mac and Linux machines. I believe MacOS automatically creates mount points under `/Volumes` when you connect using Finder. In a Linux machine you'll need to set up a `cifs` point mount and entry in `/etc/fstab`. You'll also need to figure out how the share should be authenticated. In a single-user system you can connect as the current user, but for an automated process you'll need to embed credentials somehow.